# Alternatives to iloc for searching dataframes

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a simple piece of code that iterates through a list of id's, and if an id is in a particular data frame column(in this case, the column is called `uniqueid`), it uses `iloc` to get the value from another column on the matching row and then adds it to as a value in a dictionary with the id as the key:

```
union_cols = ['uniqueid', 'FLD_ZONE', 'FLD_ZONE_1', 'ST_FIPS', 'CO_FIPS', 'CID']
union_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(records(union_gdb, union_cols))

pop_df = pd.read_csv(pop_csv, low_memory=False) # Example dataframe
uniqueid_inin = ['', 'FL1234', 'F54323', ....] # Just an example    
isin_dict = dict()

for id in uniqueid_inin:
    if (id is not '') & (id in pop_df.uniqueid.values):
        v = pop_df.loc[pop_df['uniqueid'] == id, 'Pop_By_Area'].iloc[0]
        inin_dict.setdefault(id, v)
```

This works, but it is very slow. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: `pop_df[pop_df['uniqueid'].ne('') & pop_df['uniqueid'].isin(uniqueid_inin)]`?

Comment: I am trying to get the value for the `Pop_By_Area` column in `pop_df` so that doesn't really speed it up. To clarify, the line of code I need help with is `v = pop_df.loc[pop_df['uniqueid'] == id, 'Pop_By_Area'].iloc[0]`

Comment: `cond = pop_df['uniqueid'].ne('')&...; pop_df.loc[cond, 'Pop_By_Area']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue (and make the process more efficient) I had to think about the process in a different way that took advantage of `Pandas` and didn't rely on a generic Python solution. I first had to get a list of only the uniqueids from my union_df that were absolutely in pop_df. If they were not, applying the `.isin()` method would throw an indexing error.

```
#Get list of uniqueids in pop_df
pop_uniqueids = pop_df['uniqueid'].unique()

#Get only the union_df rows where the uniqueid matches pop_uniqueid
union_df = union_df.loc[(union_df['uniqueid'].isin(pop_uniqueids))]
union_df = union_df.reset_index()
union_df = union_df.drop(columns='index')
```

When the `uniqueid_inin`  list is created from union_df (by just getting the `uniqueid`'s from rows where my `zone_status` column is equal to 'in-in'), it will only contain a subset of items that are definitely in `pop_df` and empty values are no longer an issue.  Then, I simply create a subset dataframe using the list and zip the desired column values together in a `dictionary`:

```
 inin_subset =pop_df[ pop_df['uniqueid'].isin(uniqueid_inin)]
 inin_pop_dict = dict(zip(inin_subset.uniqueid, inin_subset.Pop_By_Area))
```

I hope this technique helps.